# Retrieving data from Oracle database

Tags: asp.net, oracle, data-retrieval

I am trying to retrieve data from Oracle database and display it in ASP.net Grid. Have tried using the execute reader and the data adapter options as listed below, have succeeded in establishing the connection but no luck with data retrieval.

It does not retrieve the data at all, have done with ease in SQL but here it is taking whole lot of time with no luck.

Code snippets used:

**using execute reader**

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "user id=xxx;password=xxx;data source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=xxxx)(PORT=xxxx))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxxxx)));";

            //"+"Min Pool Size=10;Connection Lifetime=120;Connection Timeout=60;";
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from xxxx", conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

            // Close and Dispose OracleConnection object
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
```

**using Oracle dataadapter**

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("user id=xxxx;password=xxxx;data source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=xxxxx)(PORT=xxxx))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxxxxx)))"))
            //using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from xxxx", conn))
            //{
            //    conn.Open();
            //    using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            //    {
            //        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            //        dataTable.Load(reader);
            //        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
            //    }
            //}
```

Comment: Define "It does not retrieve the data at all".  When you debug this, where does it fail?  Is there an error?  Is the query executed?  What is the result of the query?  If the code is successfully executing a `SELECT` query and no records are returned, then there are no matching records.

Comment: R u getting any error??\

Comment: I am not getting any error as such with the code not returning at all after the execution of the line da.Fill(ds); I am able to get records fetched if the query is executed directly on the SQLDeveloper.

Comment: Just a small update,was able to retrieve and get the data loaded into the grid, but took hours, is there any better way of achieving this functionality as this cannot proceed as it would be creating a lock on the database ??